# Ecto.Changeset not validating

Tags: elixir, ecto

I'm experimenting with Ecto and I have issues with validating data in the `changeset()` function.

The `Schema` is as follows:

```
defmodule Barakuda.TestData do
  use Ecto.Schema

  schema "test_data" do
    field :username, :string
    field :age, :integer
  end

  def changeset(data, params \\ %{}) do
    data
    |> Ecto.Changeset.cast(params, [:username, :age])
    |> Ecto.Changeset.validate_required([:username, :age])
  end

end
```

Now lets try with invalid data:

```
iex(125)> d1=%Barakuda.TestData{id: 1, username: "polo"}
%Barakuda.TestData{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:built, "test_data">,
 age: nil, id: 1, username: "polo"}
iex(126)> Barakuda.TestData.changeset(d1).valid?        
false
```

That's ok as the `age` field is missing. The same happens if I remove the `username`. Fine!

Now, I add the following line at the end of `changeset()` (and, yes, I recompiled):

```
data
  |> Ecto.Changeset.cast(params, [:username, :age])
  |> Ecto.Changeset.validate_required([:username, :age])
  |> Ecto.Changeset.validate_number(:age, less_than: 20)
```

This is supposed to be true if `age` is strictly less than 20, e.i.: 19, 18, ... and false otherwise. Right? Lets give it a try:

```
iex(19)> d1=%Barakuda.TestData{id: 1, username: "polo", age: 15}
%Barakuda.TestData{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:built, "test_data">,
 age: 15, id: 1, username: "polo"}
iex(20)> Barakuda.TestData.changeset(d1).valid?                 
true
```

which is OK. Yet

```
iex(130)> d1=%Barakuda.TestData{id: 1, username: "polo", age: 22}
%Barakuda.TestData{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:built, "test_data">,
 age: 22, id: 1, username: "polo"}
iex(131)> Barakuda.TestData.changeset(d1).valid?                 
true
```

The same actually happens for other `validate_*` functions as for example (with or without `count: :codepoints`):

```
Ecto.Changeset.validate_length(:username, min: 6, count: :codepoints)
```

So, what am I doing wrong ?

NB: Elixir 1.5.1 and Ecto v2.2.6 (2017-09-30)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`validate_length` does not check existing fields, only "changed" fields.

> **validate_length(changeset, field, opts)**
>
> Validates a change is a string or list of the given length.

[Source](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#validate_length/3)

Since you're calling `Barakuda.TestData.changeset` with all the fields in the struct and nothing in `params` argument, no field is marked as "changed" by Ecto and `validate_length` does nothing. The correct way to do this is to pass the existing struct (with default/existing values) as the first argument and all the additions that need to be validated as the second argument, `params`. The following code should return `false` for you:

```
changeset = Barakuda.TestData.changeset(%Barakuda.TestData{}, %{id: 1, username: "polo", age: 22})
changeset.valid?
```